# Homeless people, but multiple vacant houses

Tags: tropico-5

My town has approximatly 450 citizens. There are multiple vacant houses both for the poor and the rich people, but nobody is moving in. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure their work is close enough to their housing. I can't recall right now the maximum no. units they must be from eachother, but I believe there is another Stack Exchange question that covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure they can afford the housing. Reduce the rent and increase the wages.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that they also have jobs and a market (or plantation/fisher) to get food in the vicinity. Otherwise they'll create slums were they get those things.